# Safe way to remove paint from ground wire?

Tags: grounding, paint-removal

I'm addressing an item on our house's inspection report where a GFCI outlet had been ungrounded. I turned off power at the breaker box, popped the outlet cover off and found the ground wire neatly tucked into the corner. When I pulled it out, I saw paint covering the ground as shown below:

[image: The copper wire is painted over a bit.]

From what I've researched so far, I should not attach the ground as-is, since the paint interferes with the metal-to-metal contact. Would using a chemical stripper be the best way to remove the paint? If not, what should I use?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just some sand paper will be fine. You don't want to use a chemical stripper as it may interact poorly with the copper.

Comment: The sandpaper is doing a fantastic job at removing the paint! Thank you for also posting a reason why to not use chemical stripper; I hadn't thought of that!

Comment: That said, most paint strippers will be organic solvents (methylene chloride, maybe xylene, toluene) that generally don't do much to metal, copper especially. Aqueous solutions are more of a hazard. Sandpaper is the quickest and easiest way though, or a knife if it was throughly coated.

Comment: In addition, sandpaper will remove any oxidisation making for a better electrical contact.

Answer (score 0):

If it's Latex paint, it may be able to “stripped” like normal insulation.  Even if it sticks to the metal more than normal insulation, it can be sliced off with a knife using the same motion as peeling carrots.

Answer (score -1):

I would definitely recommend some type of light abrasive, sandpaper,as mentioned is fine. (No pun), as would be steel wool.